# How to make my website responsive

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, media-queries

I'm new to bootstrap and I'm having a hard time setting my media queries with the right breaking points and I feel like my website not scaling properly. My site looks perfect when I set the @media(min-width: 1200px). How can I get my layout to look scale properly for the mobile and tablet devices?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>

        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="">

        <title>The Portfolio of Jason Murray</title>

        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link id="orginal" href="css/default-theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Varela' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

            <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
            <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>


    </head>

    <body>
        <!--=========== HEADER SECTION ================-->
        <header id="header">
          <!-- BEGIN MENU -->
          <div class="menu_area">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation"> 
              <div class="container">
              <div class="navbar-header">
                <!-- FOR MOBILE VIEW COLLAPSED BUTTON -->
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                  <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>

                <!-- LOGO -->
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Jason<span>Murray</span></a>
              </div>

              <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul id="top-menu" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right main_nav">
                  <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>               
                  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>                           
                </ul>           
              </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
              </div>     
            </nav>  
          </div><!-- END MENU -->
        </header>
         <!--=========== END HEADER SECTION ================-->

        <!--=========== MAIN CONTENT SECTION ================-->
        <div class="jumbotron">         
            <div class="container">
                <div class="image_opacity"></div> 
                <div class="caption">
                    <h2>Front-End</h2> 
                    <h2>Web Developer</h2>
                    <p>Hi, I'm Jason Murray and I have a passion for building simplistic websites.</p>
                    <a href="#" class="caption_btn">Recent Work</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--=========== END MAIN CONTENT SECTION ================-->

        <!--=========== FOOTER SECTION================-->
         <footer id="footer">
           <div class="container">
             <div class="row">
               <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                 <div class="footer_left">
                   <p>&copy; 2015 <a href="index.html" target="_blank">Jason Murray Web Design</a>. All Rights Reserved</p>
                 </div>
               </div>
               <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                 <div class="footer_right">
                   <ul class="social_nav">
                     <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
                     <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                     <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
                   </ul>
                 </div>
               </div>
             </div>
           </div>
         </footer>
        <!--=========== END FOOTER SECTION================-->
        <!-- jQuery -->
        <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

        <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        </body>

        </html>
```

CSS CODE:

```
body,html{
  overflow-x:hidden;
}
body {
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  overflow-x: hidden !important;
}

ul{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

a{ 
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #2f2f2f;

}
a:focus{
  outline: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}
h1,h2{
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif; 
}
h3,h4,h5,h6{
    font-family: 'Varela', sans-serif;  
}

h2 {
  color: #313338;  
  font-size: 72px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 57px;
  margin: 0;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
img{
 border:none;
}

/*--------------------*/
/* HEADER */
/*--------------------*/

#header{
  float: left;
  display: inline;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

/*--------.menu_area-------- */
.menu_area{
  position: absolute;
  left:0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
.navbar-default {
  background-color: #000000;
  border-color: transparent;
  padding: 12px 0px;
}
.past-main {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  margin-top: 0px;
  padding:6px 0px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
  transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;

}
#navbar{overflow-x: hidden;}

.navbar-brand {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
  color: #fff !important;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-family: 'Varela', sans-serif;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
  background-color: transparent;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover{
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #2da2c8;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #2da2c8;
}
.navbar-brand > span {
  color: #2da2c8;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus { 
  color: #2da2c8;
}


/*--------------------*/
/* MAIN CONTENT - HOME */
/*--------------------*/
.jumbotron {
  background: url("../img/lucho-49.jpg") no-repeat center center;
  -webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;
  -moz-background-size: 100% 100%;
  -o-background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  margin-top: 75px;
  height: 320px;
}
.image_opacity{
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #242434;
  margin-top: 75px;
  height: 320px;
  opacity: 0.8;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 9;
}
.caption {
  margin-top: 20%;
  padding: 5px 0;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 999;
}
.caption > h2 {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 12px;
  margin: 0 auto 10px;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: 90%;
}
.caption>p{
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 12px;    
}
.caption_btn{
    padding: 10px 15px;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 12px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.caption_btn:hover,.caption_btn:focus{
    border-color:#2da2c8;
    color: #2da2c8;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/*--------------------*/
/* FOOTER */
/*--------------------*/

#footer{
  float: left;
  display: inline;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px;
  background-color: #000;
}
.footer_left{
  float: left;
  display: inline;
  width: 100%;
}
.footer_left > p {
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
.footer_left > p a {  
  font-weight: bold;
}
.footer_right{
  float: left;
  display: inline;
  width: 100%;
}
.social_nav{
  text-align: center;  
}
.social_nav li{
  display: inline-block;
}
.social_nav li a {
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  color: #ffffff;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 18px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 35px;
  line-height: 28px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}
.social_nav li a:hover{
  color: #2da2c8;
  border-color: #2da2c8; 
}

/*----------------------------------*/
/* RESPONSIVE STYLE - MEDIA QUERIES */
/*----------------------------------*/

@media(min-width: 768px) {
.navbar-brand {color: #fff !important;font-size: 30px;font-weight: bolder;font-family: 'Varela', sans-serif;}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {font-size: 15px;}
.jumbotron {background: url("../img/lucho-49.jpg") no-repeat center center;-webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;-moz-background-size: 100% 100%;-o-background-size: 100% 100%;background-size: 100% 100%;height: 872px;}
.image_opacity{background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #242434;margin-top: 75px;height: 872px;opacity: 0.8;width: 100%;}
.caption {margin-top: 30%;position: relative;text-align: center;z-index: 999;}
.caption > h2 {color: #ffffff;font-size: 45px;font-weight: 700;line-height: 56px;margin: 0 auto 10px;padding-bottom: 8px;text-align: center;text-transform: uppercase;width: 90%;}
.caption> p {color: #ffffff;font-size: 18px;}
.caption_btn{padding: 10px 15px;border: 2px solid #fff;color: #fff;font-size: 18px;display: inline-block;text-transform: uppercase;}
.caption_btn:hover,.caption_btn:focus {border-color:#2da2c8;color: #2da2c8;text-decoration: none;}
#footer{padding: 24px;}
#footer > .container > .row {margin-right: auto;}
.footer_left > p {font-size: 13px;text-align: left;}
.social_nav{text-align: right;}
}

@media(min-width: 1200px) {
.navbar-brand {color: #fff !important;font-size: 35px;font-weight: bolder;font-family: 'Varela', sans-serif;}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {font-size: 15px;}
.jumbotron {background: url("../img/lucho-49.jpg") no-repeat center center;-webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;-moz-background-size: 100% 100%;-o-background-size: 100% 100%;background-size: 100% 100%;height: 842px;}
.image_opacity {background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #242434;margin-top: 75px;height: 842px;opacity: 0.8;width: 100%;}
.caption {margin-top: 20%;position: relative;text-align: center;z-index: 999;}
.caption > h2 {color: #ffffff;font-size: 65px;font-weight: 700;line-height: 76px;margin: 0 auto 10px;padding-bottom: 8px;text-align: center;text-transform: uppercase;width: 90%;}
.caption > p {color: #ffffff;font-size: 20px;}
.caption_btn {padding: 10px 15px;border: 2px solid #fff;color: #fff;font-size: 20px;display: inline-block;text-transform: uppercase;}
.caption_btn:hover,.caption_btn:focus {border-color:#2da2c8;color: #2da2c8;text-decoration: none;}
#footer{padding: 24px;}
.footer_left > p {font-size: 15px;text-align: left;}
.social_nav{text-align: right;}
```

Comment: Can you create a minimal example showing what you have achieved with both HTML and CSS, and then explain what is not working? It's not really clear what the issue is from your question.

Comment: I like your design simple and awesome :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the standard Bootstrap v3.3.5 media queries and corresponds with the documentation that outlines the responsive classes that are available.

```
/* Extra Small Devices, .visible-xs-* */
@media (max-width: 767px) {}

/* Small Devices, .visible-sm-* */
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {}

/* Medium Devices, .visible-md-* */
@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px) {}

/* Large Devices, .visible-lg-* */
@media (min-width: 1200px) {}
```

**Media Queries by Device**:

```
/* Large desktops and laptops */
@media (min-width: 1200px) {

}

/* Landscape tablets and medium desktops */
@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px) {

}

/* Portrait tablets and small desktops */
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {

}

/* Landscape phones and portrait tablets */
@media (max-width: 767px) {

}

/* Portrait phones and smaller */
@media (max-width: 480px) {

}
```

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities

Comment: The issue that I have with my site is that whenever I test my site in a browser (firefox as an example), I see the white space when I scale the browser. How can I get my site to show without the white spaces showing?

Comment: I would have to see an example with code to help you.

Comment: Please see my original question that I posted along with my html & css code.

Comment: You need a sticky footer, I have a [CodePen](http://codepen.io/Gothburz/pen/jbrZmK) that you can look at.

Comment: You are the man! I've gone ahead and used your footer code and it works fine. No longer see the white spacing underneath the footer.I appreciate it brother. Have a great day!

Comment: No problem Jason! I'm happy it worked for ya. Add me on Twitter if you want, same username.

Comment: I'm now seeing the white space again when I scale the browser except this time I think it has to do with my "jumbotron", "image opacity" and "caption" divs.