# How to properly structure a Bootstrap grid with rowspan

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

My goal is to visualize three images in a simple grid structure, where the first column occupies two rows, something like having rowspan=2.

[image: Just like this]

It seems easy to achieve using Bootstrap's `row` and `col-*`. The problems arise when I try to put a little padding around the images, to slightly separate one another.
I've little experience with CSS, and my trial-and-error approach is not working. I am unable to align the top and bottom borders of Image 1 with the other two.

So, what is the best practice in order to structure such a layout?  A test fiddle with my code is here:  https://jsfiddle.net/ae5wq61t/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This format would be cleaner and much easier if you used nested rows. Make sure there is a container wrapping it. I gave a class of `.bottom-right` to the row on the bottom right, then adjusted its `margin-top` to align with the picture on the left.

HTML:

```
 <div class="container">  
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
         <img class="img-responsive" src="http://vivereconglianimali.altervista.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/Tartaruga-Marina.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://vivereconglianimali.altervista.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/Tartaruga-Marina.jpg" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row bottom-right">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://vivereconglianimali.altervista.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/Tartaruga-Marina.jpg" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.bottom-right{
   margin-top: 23px;
}
```

[CODEPEN DEMO](http://codepen.io/Gothburz/pen/ZbjMpm)

Comment: I tried to naively substitude the div content (1 with <br>, 2, 3) with the image. And, as you can see [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gajdyv), it loses the bottom alignment.

Comment: I updated the demo, the nested row's need to be in a container.

Comment: if you want your images all the way across the  screen you can use ``.container-fluid`` instead.

Comment: In the updated demo I'm still seeing the images unaligned. The right-bottom image *Image 3* is not aligned with *Image 1*. Using Firefox here

Comment: I took them out of the wells and gave a slight margin-top to the bottom right div. I edited the answer to reflect this.

Comment: Yep, now it's working! Thanks! Sorry for my embarrassing low knowledge of CSS, but this isn't a bit hacky?

Comment: No problem! glad I can help, it's not too hacky because it's not a lot of code. The only thing you'll need to aware of is the bootstrap breakpoints at which your ``col-*`` will break down for smaller screens. Just mark the answer as resolved please :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33490187/how-to-make-my-website-responsive/33490473#33490473 here is a post on the bootstrap breakpoints.