# Responsive Layouts with Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have read the way people should make questions. About specific details, problems developing, stuck in some specific coding problem.
I'm afraid my question can be classified in those kind of undesirable ones, based on opinions, but as is sugested i searched google many times and couldn't find an answer. So my apologise but it goes.
Isn't responsive layouts like bootstrap a kind of regress to layouts made with tables instead of css? W3C strongly recommended use of css instead of tables to make layouts. But working with grids and columns like in bootstrap, isn't that a kind of making the same again (like with tables), just with other technologies? Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make my website responsive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33490187/how-to-make-my-website-responsive)

Answer (score 1):

I can see where you're coming from - the Bootstrap system can be compared to tables in some ways - but it is far different in others. The most obvious difference is that it essentially does do exactly what you described: it replaces tables to make a more flexible and versatile layout using CSS. While tables are fixed and clunky, the Bootstrap grid can adjust sizes of individual columns based on the size of the *viewport*. Thus allowing your website to appear as you would like on any sized screen. This feature is especially useful in the interest of mobile accessibility. Furthermore, by using CSS rather than a table, you also gain flexibility in other ways. To elaborate, you can modify or add classes to work along with the Bootstrap grid, and create effects you would never be able to with a table layout.

Answer (score 1):

Nobody has recommended against tabular layouts.  Back in HTML1 days there were only one way to make tablura layout and that was with `tables`

The tables that are not recommended are those which are coded in HTML as

```
<table> ... </table>
```

They are not flexible and cannot benefit from many of the CSS features available today.

Bootstrap on the other hand is using div's -- every cell that you are using is coded in HTML as a

```
<div> ... </div>
```

And the fact that they are coded that way they can make use of all kind of CSS features to make the content portable and usable across devices and screen sizes...

Answer (score 0):

It is in a way like tables were years ago. However, tables were still far more static and less fluid than using a grid system like Bootstrap. Modifying the CSS of your HTML elements still allows you to change the structure of a website built with Bootstrap, where with tables that was not as easy. Overriding the stock Bootstrap CSS is also simple.

I had the same thoughts as you when I first began using Bootstrap, but after you've had some time with it you will understand how it is far more flexible than tables. It is, however, less flexible then designing and coding your own CSS for your own design.

Answer (score 0):

No it is not the same thing. What you can do with a `<div>`, you can't always accomplish with `<table>`
   - playing around with JavaScript, accessing a specific column and rows will be difficult

```
$(table tr td table.......).on("click", function(){

});//you are more prone to making a mistake here with too many tags

and 
$('#ron').on("click", function(){

});
```

- Maintenance wise: div are very easy to fiddle around with than tables
  which are very rigid
- with `<table>`  you need an extra tag `<tbody>` that means more code.
- when updating your html code, having `div` instead of `table` is less cumbersome.
- Responsive design with tables is very difficult. Whilst with div, you can use most CSS properties and methods to make your website work cross-device